# Как вывести данные с другого сайта через ajax, Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ссылка http://namaz.muftyat.kz/api/times/2016/50.3/57.166667. Нужно вывести данные в таблице. Что мне использовать jsonp или CORS????

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://namaz.muftyat.kz/api/times/2016/50.3/57.166667',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            CrossDoamin: true,         
        });
```

- выдает ошибку

Comment: `Failed to load http://namaz.muftyat.kz/api/times/2016/50.3/57.166667: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://*******' is therefore not allowed access.` Похоже, что целевой сайт не разрешает получать с него данные откуда угодно. Может быть взять эту страницу на стороне сервера?

Comment: Ну я тоже начал использовать сторонний сервис, а по другому никак???

Comment: Современные браузеры не дадут вам просто стягивать данные с любых доменов кроссдоменным запросом, это не безопасно для клиента. Нужна серверная сторона, которая сделает запрос через CURL или подобные, и вернет клиенту ответ. Ей так сделать никто не может запретить

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант то, что ты и предложил

https://cors.io/?  и добавляешь туда ссылку

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://cors.io/?http://namaz.muftyat.kz/api/times/2016/50.3/57.166667', true);
xhr.send();
JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

Проверял, здесь в консоли